# iMac 27 i5 2010 HDD fan control

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, mac, fan

Since I've changed the original HDD to SSD the fan is going like crazy always at max or close to it.
Under /sys/devices/platform/applesmc786/ if I edit fan2_output to 0 the fan stops for a second before going back up to 5400rpm. I could make a script to keep writing 0 every 0.5 second to the file, bu I believe that will be a heavy burden on the machine.
I can see other files that could be useful fan2_input, fan2_manual, fan2_max, but I can't write on it even after changing permissions. Maybe writing 0 to the fan2_max will make the fan stop, but again I can't write.
Why cat I write to this files, and how to solve it?
Im on Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 0):

### Try To Open The Case And Blow The Dust Or Try To Stress Test It

For Windows Users Install Fan Control

### For Mac Users Install Mac's Fan Control

**For Ubuntu Users**
1. Do The Following Command "sudo sensors-detect"
2. Then "sudo service module-init-tools restart"

**> To Configure The Speed**
Or Read The Whole Article ----
[How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that before and is not working for me. Still I like to know why can't edit fan2_max file ?