# Cannot get fan speed

Tags: hp, fan, acpi, fancontrol, lm-sensors

I have HP Spectre 13 x360 Laptop
I cannot see or control my fan speed
[image: Thermal show]
[image: lm-sensors]

(lm-sensors is installed)

As I can in Windows using a program called SpeedFan.

[image: 1]

Here is the it's execution log:

```
Win9x:NO  64Bit:YES  GiveIO:NO  SpeedFan:YES 
I/O properly initialized
Linked ISA BUS at $0290
Scanning ISA BUS at $0290...
SuperIO Chip=SCH5027D
Found AXNS381E-256GM-B on AdvSMART
INFO : SCSI DISABLED by user or because iaStorA.sys is installed
Found Hewlett-Packard HP Spectre x360 Convertible 13
Found ACPI temperature
Found Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz
End of detection
Loaded 0 events
```

I followed [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed) tutorial and it didn't help
When I enter `sudo pwmconfig` I get this error message`/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed` 
My AMI BIOS doesn't show any thermal or sensory info. It's "Fan Always on" is Disabled.

Here is the output of `sudo sensors-detect`

```
# sensors-detect revision 6284 (2015-05-31 14:00:33 +0200)
# System: Hewlett-Packard HP Spectre x360 Convertible 13 (laptop)
# Board: Hewlett-Packard 802D
# Kernel: 4.15.0-23-generic x86_64
# Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz (6/61/4)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): y
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): y
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0x8987
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): y
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): y
Found unknown SMBus adapter 8086:9ca2 at 0000:00:1f.3.
Sorry, no supported PCI bus adapters found.

Next adapter: Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): y
Adapter doesn't support all probing functions.
Some addresses won't be probed.

Next adapter: Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): y
Adapter doesn't support all probing functions.
Some addresses won't be probed.
Client at address 0x1c can not be probed - unload all client drivers first!

Next adapter: i915 gmbus vga (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpc (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpb (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpd (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y

Next adapter: DPDDC-A (i2c-6)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y

Next adapter: DPDDC-C (i2c-7)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y


Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)y
Successful!

Monitoring programs won't work until the needed modules are
loaded. You may want to run '/etc/init.d/kmod start'
to load them.
```

Is it a missing ACPI linux driver for this motherboard ?

Does the on-board GPU have thermal info also ?

Thank you

Comment: post the output of `sudo sensors-detect`

Comment: did you try to install `lm-sensors` like it say in the 2nd picture?

Comment: @damadam Yes 
`roey@hpx360-13:~$ sudo apt show lm-sensors 
[sudo] password for roey: 
Package: lm-sensors
Version: 1:3.4.0-4
Priority: extra
Section: universe/utils
`

Comment: and have you test it?

Comment: @damadam Yes with several GNOME extensions and some apps (sensor-unity and indicator sensors) still I can't get the fans speed nor the GPU thermal

Comment: It's only detecting coretemp which is for monitoring the cpu temps.  There is one unknown Super IO detected, but from what I can tell, no one has written a driver for it, if it's even possible.

Comment: @Roey could this link help? https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=243538 The guy seems to have the same computer as yours. I am having your same problem with an HP Spectre x360 14 ea0775. That link didn't work for me though =/