# MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: fancontrol

Is there a way to **control fan speed** of MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS because it heats up quickly without intensive workload.Pls Help

Comment: Do you hear the fan running pretty loud already when it heats up?

Comment: Nope Its quiet like fans are not speeding up.When i used to use mac os and windows 10, fan speed would increase during workload and i also could manually control fan speed...But ubuntu is not able to do so  neither can i manually increase fan speed.Pls help me how can i do so that my macbook reamains cool and work efficiently

Comment: Try following the instruction from an old answers, it suppose to still work. It will help you spin up the fan, I'd suggest turn the fan on the near the max and keep it that way for cpu longevity. https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed

Answer (score 1):

Installing this fan control daemon from the repos has worked for me on my mid-2012:

```
$ sudo apt install macfanctld
```

Reboot and follow that up with installing lm-sensors and checking your core temps:

```
$ sudo apt install lm-sensors

$ sensors
```

If you swap the install order, you can test both before and after temps.