# Lenovo high temperatures and loud fan

Tags: lenovo, battery, overheating, temperature, fancontrol

i have Lenovo Y50-70 with Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and problem with high temperatures and loud fan and fast empty battery

This is not a problem in Windows

i read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed) post , when i type sudo pwmconfig this error show:

```
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

what can i do?

and sorry for bad English

Comment: Fast battery drain, high temp, loud fan...see what is using up the CPU with the `top` command.

Answer (score 0):

I've got recently exactly the same problem, also `no pwm-capable sensor modules installed` so I've decided to implement my own fan manager. I've droped from 85° to 60° with it.

Give it a try, you can find installation and usage instructions here : https://github.com/ichiriac/ubuntu-smart-fan