# How to control fans on Gigabyte Z390 AORUS MASTER?

Tags: drivers, fan

I tried to use lm-sensors and fancontrol as explained in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed), but pwmcontrol tells me that no pwm-control sensor modules are available.

[This Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/7h5r32/is_it_possible_to_control_fan_speeds_on_gigabyte/) seems to indicate that it is not trivial/possible to do it, but does anyone as an update on it?

The Windows application allows me to control the fans without problem.

```
# lshw -C system
description: Desktop Computer
product: Z390 AORUS MASTER (Default string)
vendor: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
version: Default string
serial: Default string
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-3.1 dmi-3.1 smp vsyscall32
configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop family=Default string sku=Default string uuid=E002D503-5E04-AB05-E206-3E0700080009
```

Answer (score 0):

In latest motherboards you can manage fans in BIOS. If you can't find fan control in BIOS, take a look at [firmare updates](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/Z390-AORUS-MASTER-G2-Edition-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios) for your MB.