# Show Lenovo Yoga 730 fan speed in Kubuntu

Tags: fan, fancontrol, intel-cpu

On my Lenovo Yoga 730-15IWL with a i5-8265U CPU, the `sensors-detect` command cannot detect the fans, so `sensors` cannot show them either.

How can I show the fans speed on such a system?

Comment: lm-sensors does not detect fans in lenovo y50 either.

Comment: Did you try this [ https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc ] project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bunch of digging and investigation for the Super I/O chip used by the LNVNB161216 motherboard, it seems that the fan speed is neither exposed nor controllable by *any* operating system. The chip in question is from Nuvoton and operates independently.

---

for other models, you can try this:

You may need to make some changes to your `/etc/default/grub`, then run `sensors-detect` again. Try this:

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub` as root
   `sudo vi /etc/default/grub`
2. Add/Edit the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` value so that it reads:
   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_enforce_resources=lax"`
3. Save the file and close
4. Update Grub with `sudo update-grub`
5. Re-scan the hardware with `sudo sensors-detect`

The fan speed should now be visible when using applications that display this data.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing this extension
`sudo apt install gnome-tweaks gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor`
after executing this command logout and login again and after that see that the app named extension is added to the show aplication list and enable system monitor in the extension app[image].After that a system monitor tab will be added to the top open it and select preferences and search for fan and select display it.Hope this help.[image]

Comment: Did this helped you?@rubo77

Comment: At first I thought yes, but it revealed to me later, that the label was on the left so **it didn't show my fan either** ... I guess @Matigo was right in the end. It is not possible with my model.