# GUI to Control fanspeed in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, ubuntu-mate, ubuntu-core

is there any GUI Software to control fanspeeds in Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[fancontrol-gui](https://github.com/Maldela/fancontrol-gui) is a GUI for [fancontrol](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed#46135) which is part of lm_sensors. It uses the KAuth module of the KDE Frameworks 5 to write the generated config file. Furthermore it communicates with systemd via dbus to control the fancontrol service.

Install the build requirements (tested in Ubuntu 18.04):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libkf5config-dev libkf5auth-dev libkf5package-dev libkf5declarative-dev libkf5coreaddons-dev libkf5dbusaddons-dev libkf5kcmutils-dev libkf5i18n-dev libkf5plasma-dev libqt5core5a libqt5widgets5 libqt5gui5 libqt5qml5 extra-cmake-modules qtbase5-dev libkf5notifications-dev qml-module-org-kde-kirigami2 qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qtquick-controls2 qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qt-labs-settings qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel cmake build-essential gettext git
```

Install fancontrol-gui:

```
git clone https://github.com/Maldela/fancontrol-gui.git
cd fancontrol-gui
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DBUILD_KCM=on -DBUILD_PLASMOID=on
make -j
sudo make install
```

Comment: In case this somehow does not work, it might make sense to first properly setup the CLI/backend. See this mess: https://askubuntu.com/a/46135/308869

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5I18n.so.5.68.0: undefined reference to `qt_version_tag@Qt_5.12'
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libKF5CoreAddons.so.5.68.0: undefined reference to `QMetaObject::invokeMethodImpl(QObject*, QtPrivate::QSlotObjectBase*, Qt::ConnectionType, void*)@Qt_5'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [helper/CMakeFiles/fancontrol_gui-helper.dir/build.make:99: bin/fancontrol_gui-helper] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:434: helper/CMakeFiles/fancontrol_gui-helper.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2