# messed up fan speed setting how to reset

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, fan

So i run ubuntu server 22.04.2
The problem was my gpu fan makes noise when it runs, so i was trying to mess with fan speed controls so I ran a couple of commands that I have mentioned down
`pwmconfig`
`fancontrol`
It said to run fan manually to test or something so I said yes to all and now I think they don't automatically turn off. How can I reset it?

After doing that I also tried installing a GUI for fan speed control
which had following commands from this website [GUI to Control fanspeed in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1166768/gui-to-control-fanspeed-in-ubuntu)

Install the build requirements (tested in Ubuntu 18.04):

`sudo apt update sudo apt install libkf5config-dev libkf5auth-dev libkf5package-dev libkf5declarative-dev libkf5coreaddons-dev libkf5dbusaddons-dev libkf5kcmutils-dev libkf5i18n-dev libkf5plasma-dev libqt5core5a libqt5widgets5 libqt5gui5 libqt5qml5 extra-cmake-modules qtbase5-dev libkf5notifications-dev qml-module-org-kde-kirigami2 qml-module-qtquick-dialogs qml-module-qtquick-controls2 qml-module-qtquick-layouts qml-module-qt-labs-settings qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel cmake build-essential gettext git`

Install fancontrol-gui:

`git clone https://github.com/Maldela/fancontrol-gui.git cd fancontrol-gui mkdir build cd build cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DBUILD_KCM=on -DBUILD_PLASMOID=on make -j sudo make install`

Now I wanna reset all of it how can I do that?

Comment: fancontrol likely won't work with a GPU fan.  post a copy of your `/etc/fancontrol` file and `sensors` output.

Comment: Why the Ubuntu-touch tag and the application-development tag? They do not seem to have anything to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to disable fancontrol and then reboot to get the fans back into auto mode.  If they don't switch back to auto, there may be one more step involving finding the PWM path (look in /etc/fancontrol) and there should be some pwm#_mode 'files' that are set to 1, just need to switch them to 0.

```
sudo systemctl disable fancontrol
```

You could also run `pwmconfig` again to configure it properly, or manually edit `/etc/fancontrol` to behave the way you want the fans to.  `man fanctonrol` for help with it, or check out [Cannot configure Fan Speed with pwmconfig](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1187812/cannot-configure-fan-speed-with-pwmconfig)