# How to adjust CPU & GPU Fans start temperature in my Ubuntu 19.04 on Dell g5 15 ( 5587 ) laptop?

Tags: dell, laptop, fan

Looks like there is no such option in BIOS and I'm unable to find any software to do it from the OS. My laptop model does not appear in https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a7f89616b7376495424f682b6086e0c391a89a1d/drivers/hwmon/dell-smm-hwmon.c#L952

Comment: lm-sensors https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lm_sensors and s-tui https://github.com/amanusk/s-tui/blob/master/README.md will show you temp data; looking now for a solution to control fans

Comment: Yes, lm-sensors display temperatures correctly.

Comment: Answer from https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed doesn't work for me, sensors-detect unable to find any pwm controlled device.

Comment: Did you try https://askubuntu.com/a/772370/197910

Comment: @Mike666 Most likely you fans can't be controlled from OS.

Comment: @K7AAY I tried it and turns out it works, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[powersave](http://powersave.sourceforge.net/powersave/Thermal.html) will control fans on some, not all PCs. [thermald](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues) may also help.  You may need to install the [i8kutils package for Dells.](https://askubuntu.com/a/772370/197910)

Once installed, you will need to find which sensors correspond with which fans by experimentation and research, then edit configuration files as explained in the above link to enable control and change the set points.

`sudo modprobe i8k force=1` might enable *dell_smm* devices to appear and sensors to show fan[1,2] rpm so you could configure a desirable thermal profile in /etc/i8kmon.conf . You might need to do *force=1* since the laptop is missing from https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a7f89616b7376495424f682b6086e0c391a89a1d/drivers/hwmon/dell-smm-hwmon.c#L952

Comment: sudo modprobe i8k force=1 worked for me. dell_smm devices was appeared, sensors now show fan[1,2] rpm, and I was able to configure desired thermal profile in /etc/i8kmon.conf. I need to do force=1 because my laptop was missing from https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a7f89616b7376495424f682b6086e0c391a89a1d/drivers/hwmon/dell-smm-hwmon.c#L952

Comment: I shoehorned your findings into the answer post hoc because comments can get stripped away whereas answers will be preserved. Also voted to reopen the question as non-duplicated.