# How to control fan speed on ThinkStation by Lenovo?

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, fancontrol

I have found few questions([1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed),[2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fan_speed_control)) and articles on the web about how to control fan speed. However, it seems that Lenovo ThinkPads need to be configured differently([1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)). However, there is nothing about ThinkStations. Did anyone try to get fan speed control on ThinkStation? If Yes, did it work and how did you set it up?

Here what I have tried:

Running `sudo sensors-detect` shows only one sensor

```
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
```

Following instruction at [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fan_speed_control#ThinkPad_laptops), installed thinkpad

```
$ sudo apt-get install thinkfan
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
thinkfan is already the newest version (0.9.3-2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-51 linux-headers-4.15.0-51-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-55 linux-headers-4.15.0-55-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-51-generic linux-image-4.15.0-55-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-51-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-55-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 332 not upgraded.
```

but I cannot load the module

```
$ sudo modprobe thinkpad_acpi
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'thinkpad_acpi': No such device
```

Here is the output from sensors-detect

```
$ sudo sensors-detect 
# sensors-detect revision 6284 (2015-05-31 14:00:33 +0200)
# System: LENOVO 30X50045XX [ThinkStation P330]
# Board: LENOVO 3138
# Kernel: 4.15.0-101-generic x86_64
# Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz (6/158/10)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): Yes
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): Yes
/dev/port: Operation not permitted

Some systems (mainly servers) implement IPMI, a set of common interfaces
through which system health data may be retrieved, amongst other things.
We first try to get the information from SMBIOS. If we don't find it
there, we have to read from arbitrary I/O ports to probe for such
interfaces. This is normally safe. Do you want to scan for IPMI
interfaces? (YES/no): Yes
/dev/port: Operation not permitted

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): Y
/dev/port: Operation not permitted

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): yes
Found unknown SMBus adapter 8086:a323 at 0000:00:1f.4.
Sorry, no supported PCI bus adapters found.

Next adapter: Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): yes 
Adapter doesn't support all probing functions.
Some addresses won't be probed.
Client found at address 0x51
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1033'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1034'...                     No
Probing for `SPD EEPROM'...                                 No
Client found at address 0x52
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1033'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1034'...                     No
Probing for `SPD EEPROM'...                                 No
Client found at address 0x53
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1033'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1034'...                     No
Probing for `SPD EEPROM'...                                 No
Client found at address 0x58
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7462'...                     No
Probing for `Andigilog aSC7512'...                          No
Client found at address 0x5c
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7462'...                     No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1072'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1073'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1074'...                               No
Client found at address 0x73
Probing for `FSC Poseidon I'...                             No
Probing for `FSC Poseidon II'...                            No
Probing for `FSC Scylla'...                                 No
Probing for `FSC Hermes'...                                 No
Probing for `FSC Heimdal'...                                No
Probing for `FSC Heracles'...                               No
Probing for `FSC Hades'...                                  No
Probing for `FSC Syleus'...                                 No

Next adapter: Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): yes
Adapter doesn't support all probing functions.
Some addresses won't be probed.
Client found at address 0x51
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1033'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1034'...                     No
Probing for `SPD EEPROM'...                                 No
Client found at address 0x52
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1033'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1034'...                     No
Probing for `SPD EEPROM'...                                 No
Client found at address 0x53
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1033'...                     No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1034'...                     No
Probing for `SPD EEPROM'...                                 No
Client found at address 0x58
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7462'...                     No
Probing for `Andigilog aSC7512'...                          No
Client found at address 0x5c
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7462'...                     No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1072'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1073'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1074'...                               No
Client found at address 0x73
Probing for `FSC Poseidon I'...                             No
Probing for `FSC Poseidon II'...                            No
Probing for `FSC Scylla'...                                 No
Probing for `FSC Hermes'...                                 No
Probing for `FSC Heimdal'...                                No
Probing for `FSC Heracles'...                               No
Probing for `FSC Hades'...                                  No
Probing for `FSC Syleus'...                                 No

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpb (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpc (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: i915 gmbus misc (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes


Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpd (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 
Next adapter: DPDDC-C (i2c-6)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: DPDDC-D (i2c-7)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): yes

Next adapter: DPDDC-E (i2c-8)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y


Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)
```

Comment: Generally laptops don't follow the steps using `sensors-detect` and `fancontrol`, some do, these are for PWM enabled motherboards.  Laptops are often ACPI, you will often have a `/proc/acpi/ibm/fan` path available if it is controllable via ACPI.  thinkfan is acpi based, as is thermald which tends to be installed and running on 18.04 with laptops.

Comment: ThinkStation is a desktop

Comment: ah, didn't know that. What does `sensors-detect` output?  Can you add the full output of the SuperIO section?

Comment: Done. But it doesn't look that instructive to me. The bottom line is that it found only one sensor :)

Comment: `/dev/port: Operation not permitted`  This is likely because secure boot is enabled.  I'd look into how to disable it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you cannot control it at OS level regardless of Windows or Linux, and your only control is at boot (BIOS).
That is based on the following posts: https://github.com/vmatare/thinkfan/issues/95 and several others on the Lenovo Users Forum

Answer (score 1):

[image: bios]

The ThinkCentre M70s doesn’t seem to let the OS control the fan. It is set statically by the BIOS. Very smart indeed!