# Unable to control fan speed on Lenovo Desktop m58p by pwmconfig

Tags: 22.04, lenovo, fan, fancontrol

I got hold of [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1238028/924735) article. I am having heating issues. But I am unable to figure out how to proceed.

```
abhishek@abhishek:~$ sudo sensors-detect
# sensors-detect version 3.6.0
# System: LENOVO 7630BB5 [ThinkCentre M58p]
# Board: LENOVO LENOVO
# Kernel: 5.15.0-60-generic x86_64
# Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E8400 @ 3.00GHz (6/23/10)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need                                                             
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe                                                               
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,                                                                
unless you know what you're doing.                                                                                             
                                                                                                                               
Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.                                                       
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): YES
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 17h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Hygon Family 18h thermal sensors...                         No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): YES
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0x8b02

Some systems (mainly servers) implement IPMI, a set of common interfaces
through which system health data may be retrieved, amongst other things.
We first try to get the information from SMBIOS. If we don't find it
there, we have to read from arbitrary I/O ports to probe for such
interfaces. This is normally safe. Do you want to scan for IPMI
interfaces? (YES/no): YES
Probing for `IPMI BMC KCS' at 0xca0...                      No
Probing for `IPMI BMC SMIC' at 0xca8...                     No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): YES
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): YES
Using driver `i2c-i801' for device 0000:00:1f.3: Intel ICH10

Next adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at 1c20 (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): YES
Client found at address 0x50
Handled by driver `at24' (already loaded), chip type `spd'
    (note: this is probably NOT a sensor chip!)
Client found at address 0x51
Handled by driver `at24' (already loaded), chip type `spd'
    (note: this is probably NOT a sensor chip!)
Client found at address 0x52
Handled by driver `at24' (already loaded), chip type `spd'
    (note: this is probably NOT a sensor chip!)
Client found at address 0x53
Handled by driver `at24' (already loaded), chip type `spd'
    (note: this is probably NOT a sensor chip!)
Client found at address 0x5c
Probing for `Analog Devices ADT7462'...                     No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1072'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1073'...                               No
Probing for `SMSC EMC1074'...                               No

Next adapter: i915 gmbus ssc (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): YES

Next adapter: i915 gmbus vga (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): YES

Next adapter: i915 gmbus panel (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): YES

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpc (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): YES

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpb (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): YES

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpd (i2c-6)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): YES

Next adapter: AUX C/DP C (i2c-7)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): YES
Client found at address 0x18
...
...
...
Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: 

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)YES
Successful!

Monitoring programs won't work until the needed modules are
loaded. You may want to run '/etc/init.d/kmod start'
to load them.

Unloading cpuid... OK

abhishek@abhishek:~$ cat /etc/modules
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.


# Generated by sensors-detect on Wed Feb  1 20:43:13 2023
# Chip drivers
coretemp
```

But then when I do, pwmconfig, I get the following error:

```
abhishek@abhishek:~$ sudo pwmconfig
# pwmconfig version 3.6.0
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
abhishek@abhishek:~$
```

Please can any one tell me of any hack? What I want is to set the fan speed to max.

Currently, the fan spins quite slowly. But when I remove all the DIMMs in the slots, the fans spin at maxed speed. I want that maxed out speed all the time, so that there is no heating issue.

```
abhishek@abhishek:~$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +80.0°C  (high = +78.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:       +78.0°C  (high = +78.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

No RPM information is stated either. In my home town, I had Intel boards, for them, controlling fan speed in Linux was simple. Also, `sensors` command used to show the fan RPM as well.

Now, I want maxed-out fan speed. The processor fan uses the usual 4 pin connector, (GND, +12 V, PWM, SENSE).

Comment: The machine may not support what you are trying to do.

Comment: `Found unknown chip with ID 0x8b02` need to identify what driver goes with that chip.  It's possible sensors-detect can identify 0x8b00 but not 0x8b02, and if that's the case, you may be able to use the driver for 0x8b00.  It usually involves digging through the sensors-detect source code and looking for 0x8b which I believe is the manufacturer code and modprobe their drivers to see if they work.

Comment: I did some digging in https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/hwmon and I couldn't find anything using a 0x8b for identification, let alone the full 0x8b02.  It looks the system is over 10 years old, so I wouldn't count on anyone to write a driver for it (unless you are up for learning).

Comment: @rtaft my bad then