# /usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed | Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, fan, temperature, lm-sensors

I've follow this `https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed` and many others posts and tutorials, but always stop on this error: `/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed.`

I am using a notebook.

Comment: laptops usually don't have chips that support pwm on them.  Double check `sensors-detect` and look over the SuperIO section to see if it found anything.  You might have better luck with some of the acpi based solutions like thinkfan or thermald.

Comment: I have tried the thermald solution, and after a lot of tests my `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml` became this https://pastebin.pl/view/1e3357ac. I ran sudo service thermald restart between each test, but it stills not work. And unfortunately thinkpad  does not works on my notebook just on thinkpad notebooks. `/proc/acpi/ibm/fan: No such file or directory
Error opening /proc/acpi/ibm/fan. Is this a computer really Thinkpad? Is the thinkpad_acpi module loaded? Are you running thinkfan with root privileges?` I've followed this https://gist.github.com/Yatoom/1c80b8afe7fa47a938d3b667ce234559