# Fan sensors all read 0 RPM after using pwmcontrol

Tags: fan, fancontrol

I was trying to configure my fan speeds and the process went fairly normal the first time. (Instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/46135/1120956))  I must have messed up somewhere along the way, and now when I try to restart the process I get this kind of message:

```
# pwmconfig version 3.6.0
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

Found the following devices:
   hwmon0 is AC
   hwmon1 is acpitz
   hwmon2 is BAT0
   hwmon3 is coretemp
   hwmon4 is pch_skylake
   hwmon5 is iwlwifi_1
   hwmon6 is dell_smm

Found the following PWM controls:
   hwmon6/pwm1           current value: 0

Giving the fans some time to reach full speed...
Found the following fan sensors:
   hwmon6/fan1_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!

There are no working fan sensors, all readings are 0.
Make sure you have a 3-wire fan connected.
You may also need to increase the fan divisors.
See doc/fan-divisors for more information.
```

The fan has reset to 0 RPM and I don't know how to get it back up to normal speed.  If I go to sensors the RPM stays at 0, if I use `xsensors` I still don't get any higher RPM.  I have tried to add a load to the CPU to check if the fan is simply not on because it has no load but the temps got up to 80 C before I quit the stress test.  Is there a way to simply reset everything back to normal so that the fan will be configured as default?  Please help, I am slightly scared for my computer and it would be unusable if I can't use the fan.

Comment: Which computer are you using?

Comment: I am using an Inspiron 13 inch 5378 by Dell

Comment: Somehow, my computer has now revved up the fans again.  I don't know what happened  and while it is a relief that my fan is working, I am still confused why ```pwmconfig``` returned an error.

Comment: Which answer were you doing? If you chose the accepted answer, did you set the grub config to have `acpi_enforce_resources=lax`?  That doesn't seem to be in the main instructions on that post.  Either way, the first answer is PWM based which laptops usually don't work well with.  Look at the answer that has i8kutils in it since it's a Dell.  Thinkfan may work well too.