# How do I control the CPU fan speed on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: cpu, fan

Is there a way to control the CPU fan speed in Ubuntu 20.04? I am using an older Dell Desktop.

Comment: It’s a Desktop computer, mid-tower. I will check the BIOS settings for a setup variable.

Comment: Run `sensors-detect`, if it has pwm controllable fans, you should see something detected in the SuperIO section.

Comment: My system does not have PWM controlled fans, so there is no way to control the fans in my old system. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yea, it needs to have a 4pin connector on the fan to be able to control it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)