# Put the fan off

Tags: fan

Is there a way to put the fan off on ubuntu 20.04. The fan is broken and make a lot of noise. I have to fix it up. For the moment, to stop it, I have to open the cap on my computer and force it to stop manually.

Comment: Have you tried unplugging it?  If this is your only source of CPU cooling, you probably ought to get it fixed first.

Comment: The fan must be connected. If I restart the computer and the fan is unplugged, it won't work.

Comment: From the terminal, this is no way to stop it or at least slow it down ... verrry very slow?

Comment: Here is the top search result on Ask Ubuntu for "fan speed control": [How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)

Comment: If the motherboard supports PWM, you can easily do this using fancontrol. See the instructions in the link above.