# Almost impossible to set up fans

Tags: hardware, fan, overheating, configure

I'm not a techie but I've come a long way. Maybe someone can help me. Maybe there's just an app to change your fans that I haven't found.

I've looked everywhere for help tools, tips or explanations but I can't find the solution.

How do I set up my fans? Many forums are very old and don't work, in my opinion. Whether it concerns specific hardware such as Dell or IBM. I have an **ASUS** with 3 connection points with 4 pins. I have connected fans with 4 pins. In the BIOS it is already at its lowest. *To be clear, I have an ASUS NOT a Dell or IBM.*

In `sudo pwmconfig` test I can clearly hear the fans making less noise. Setup is very difficult. When I have done it and save I get the document `/etc/fancontrol`.

When I start `systemctl status fancontrol.service` I get:

```
systemctl status fancontrol.service
● fancontrol.service - fan speed regulator
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fancontrol.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2021-07-09 11:56:51 CEST; 22s ago
       Docs: man:fancontrol(8)
             man:pwmconfig(8)
    Process: 7742 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/fancontrol --check (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Note: **`Active: failed`**

Then I went to see what it says in `/lib/systemd/system/fancontrol.service`. In it it refers to `PIDFile=/run/fancontrol.pid` but it doesn't exist.

Now I'm stuck. I don't know what to do now. Does anyone know what I should do?

Comment: Try to run manually failed command and look at it's output: `/usr/sbin/fancontrol --check`

Comment: There is no `/usr/sbin/fancontrol`. Is there another place I can find it?

Comment: Try this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/46135/917609 or maybe just install fancontrol with `sudo apt-get update -y` and `sudo apt-get install -y fancontrol`

Comment: Thanks! It will take me a while to complete that step list. lol I was looking for this.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the solution. A lot is still about Dell and IBM etc. It seems like only these PCs have fans. lol Is there really no software controller or something?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you because of my poor English. I'm deleting this wrong comment.

Comment: I found tuxedo control. This one is interesting and I'm getting it to work. Unfortunately it only sees my CPU but I can't control anything with it. Maybe someone can help with this? https://github.com/tuxedocomputers/tuxedo-control-center/