# How to check if my fans working correctly

Tags: fan, sensors

I own a hp laptop and recently I wonder if my fans work correctly.

Assuming that I have always been based on a Windows experience and with that operating system, the fans were always activated and made a great noise!
With Ubuntu instead, my computer has become so silent to do so to make me worry about my fans' work.

So after downloaded and configurated `sensors`, this is the output:

```
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +51.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:        +49.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:        +51.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

BAT1-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          10.90 V  
curr1:         1.76 A  

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:            N/A  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +52.0°C  (crit = +104.0°C)
temp2:        +52.0°C  (crit = +104.0°C)
temp3:        +27.8°C
```

As you can see, there is no data on the fans and it worries me.
Any ideas? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Pay more attention to the temperatures of those the components that the fans are supposed to be cooling.

If they stay cool, then the fans are doing their job.

If they don't stay cool, then you have a problem that must be solved.

Comment: Fortunately, the temperatures are always normal, but how you can see the command 'sensors' does not show me the fans' data, if it can serve I am using a Radeon as a graphics card.

Answer (score 0):

I presume your machine is devoid of packages that help to control the fan speed. You may try installing the packages `fancontrol` or `thinkfan` or `dell-bios-fan-control.` The instructions to configure the packages are [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed). Thereafter, You may try the Gnome extension [Freon](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/841/freon/) that provides the fan speed and temperature.

Comment: Yes, I use Gnome! I've installed this extension but again, it doesn't show me the fan data (show fan speed option is on), only the temperature