# Can't properly set up fancontrol

Tags: fancontrol

I tried setting up fancontrol, but the pwmconfig command seemed not to work. I also built fancontrol-gui, but it doesn't show any fans. I can't figure out why I can't set it up.

### Additional information

- Distro: Kubuntu 21.10
- [Setup guide I followed](https://askubuntu.com/a/46135/1480994)
- Laptop Model: HP EliteBook 8470w

Comment: Apologies, but there's not enough information here to work with. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you're running (1) the brand/model of your machine (2) how you tried setting up `fancontrol` and/or `pwmconfig`. With this, it may be possible to offer some pointers 

Comment: @matigo I edited the question and added some additional information.