# Soft bricked my laptop with ls-sensors on ubuntu

Tags: display, laptop, battery

I was testing out Linux and wanted to be able to control fan speed and was fool enough to follow the answer of this question ([How to control fan speed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)) without reading carefully the warnings.

After using `sudo ls-sensors detect` and `sudo service kmod start` (step 2-3), while using my laptop on battery, it just died. I was able to turn it back only after plugging the power cable. However, battery was shown to be 0% charge, it wouldn't charge, and if I disconnect the power cable the computer turns off.

Additionally, the laptop display and the trackpad are not being detected as well. Using an external monitor (and a mouse) I can use it almost normally. However, I can't see anything before the log in screen (booting screen), so I can't access the BIOS.

The laptop is an MSI gs65 thin 8RF. Seems a really difficult scenario, but I would  appreciate any help trying to get it back to normal. I can access Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS through blind keystrokes.

Thanks.

Comment: You have the same problem in both Ubuntu and Windows? I would take the machine for repair.

Comment: The battery and display problem, yes, in both. The trackpad works fine in Ubuntu but not in windows. I think I will try taking it to a repair shop but wanted to know if someone knew something about it first.