# Overheating despite the cooler

Tags: shutdown, overheating

I don't know whether it is a software or hardware issue, but my notebook has been having overheating problems despite the cooler working. It comes on every few minutes, but only runs for a very short time before shutting down once again. After 10 minutes or so using the computer, it will randomly turn off once again. As I've had a long history of overheating problems with this notebook before, and seeing how hot it is once it shuts down, I can only assume it is acting up again, but this time I don't have any idea of how to solve it.

Comment: Ok … but at least tell us what your hardware and os are! So far we know you have a notebook that gets hot and has had overheating problems before. There’s not much to go on!

Answer (score 0):

Try using [fancontrol](https://askubuntu.com/a/46135/1667264). Set the fan on full speed.

1. If you hear fan spinning and feel air blowing out from the laptop, but the laptop still overheats and shuts down, it is likely HW problem. Maybe dried out thermal paste on the CPU or bad contact of cooler and CPU or too much dust present in heatsink.
2. If you configure fan to constant full speed, but the fan does not keep spinning, it's likely HW issue - something wrong with the fan itself.
3. If the fan spins and laptop keeps working, then you have had SW issue. In this case manually configure some fan curves in fancontrol not to have so loud fan when idle and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Vents are often clogged. Ideally, opening the laptop and using some pressurized air, something can be done.

If the heating is not a problem with direct power, but is a problem while working out of a battery, then the battery is suspect. It could be heading toward failure. Sadly, some Lithium-Cadmium ones even fire-up and/or explode. Hopefully rarely.

Hard drives that are near full capacity and/or have some failing blocks that cause constant read attempts, would also spin more than necessary and can warm up a laptop.