Fan not working in ubuntu 24.04 LTS (6.8.0-45-generic)
I've stress test the laptop until cpu temperature hit 90 Celcius but the fan not spinning at all. In windows, fan working fine with Omen Utilities. fan-control and nbfc have no working configuration. sensors-detect says that fan is controlled by acpi not the os.
I tried dumping the register of EC but cannot find which one to enable the fan control.
specs:
Product: OMEN by HP Gaming Laptop 16-xf0xxx
OS: 24.04 LTS
Kernel: 6.8.0-45-generic

acpi output:
Battery 0: Full, 100%
Battery 0: design capacity 6320 mAh, last full capacity 5556 mAh = 87%
Adapter 0: on-line
Thermal 0: ok, -273.2 degrees C
Thermal 0: trip point 0 switches to mode critical at temperature 110.0 degrees C
Thermal 1: ok, 40.0 degrees C
Thermal 1: trip point 0 switches to mode hot at temperature 113.0 degrees C
Cooling 0: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 1: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 2: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 3: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 4: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 5: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 6: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 7: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 8: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 9: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 10: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 11: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 12: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 13: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 14: Processor 0 of 3
Cooling 15: Processor 0 of 3


At you own risk see the answer at the following link: - https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed

@david I already tried most of the answer and nothing seems work.
