# Why does whoopsie increasingly take more CPU?

Tags: performance, memory, whoopsie

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I've been following whoopsie with the top program and noticed something strange.

In the afternoon the daemon process was only using up to 2% of CPU power.

But during the evening this slowly increased to sometimes taking up to 40% of CPU power.

I am running a 10 year old machine, but even VLC which is normally running OK was having problems running smoothly due to this increase in usage.

Since i am running an old machine, should I just switch whoopsie off (as descrribed in [What is the 'whoopsie' process and how can I remove it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135540/what-is-the-whoopsie-process-and-how-can-i-remove-it)) or is there a way to let whoopsie behave less CPU hungry?

Comment: Well, I just notice this bug filed: [Huge CPU loading by whoopsie & NetworkManager tandem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/whoopsie-daisy/+bug/1056393).  You might be able to confirm that new report.

Comment: @Ed Yes, I see the tandem combination with NetworkManager as well, also I believe deja-dup-monito to be involved. One thing which strikes me with this bug #1056393: when i also run the torrent program transmission, i can strongly see the mentioned tandem increasing cpu load. I guess transmission (during download) involves the NetworkManager and somehow triggers the bug. I will have a look to see if i can add my experience to the bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got an idea as to how you could fix your problem: as a temporary measure you could cap the CPU usage of 'whoopsie' by using a program called [CPU Limit](http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/).

You can download it below:

[image: Install via the software center]

This should ensure at least while watching movies that your film remains lag-free and once you've capped it, it shouldn't bother you until you next shutdown.I've found a well explained tutorial [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-limit-cpu-usage-of-a-process-with-cpulimit-debian-ubuntu) if you need more information on how to install it and use it.

**However** as this isn't a permanent cap you'd need to get your Ubuntu to run it at startup each time if you want it to be capped on a more permanent basis. I'm not an expert on what commands you'd need to run but I think it should be possible to get it to run and limit the process at startup ([see this post if you don't know how to set apps/processes to run at startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-to-start-applications-at-startup-automatically)).

I'd suggest you try out CPU Limit and then if you're satisfied as to how well it copes with your problem and would like it to run at start-up you can use the instructions posted [here by hhlp](https://askubuntu.com/a/9384/77178) and by adding the following line:

```
cpulimit -e whoopsie -l 3 &
```

To the /etc/rc.local file it will run properly on every startup with Whoopsie capped at 3% cpu usage.

Ideally if it's a bug as commented it might be solved sometime soon, but until then this is the way I'd go about to stop the problem being an issue.

Comment: I've tried out your idea of using cpulimit. It works fine on processes I own, but it does not seem to work on processes owned by root (like whoopsie is).

Comment: you need to run the command with `sudo` in front, that will make sure you have the root privileges, it'll ask for your password and then do it normally

Comment: I've posted a useful link if you're not familiar with it [HERE](http://askubuntu.com/questions/70534/difference-between-su-sudo-s-sudo-i). It should work properly that way, but don't hesitate to post a new comment if the problem persists, if it works I'll edit this into the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comments. I appreciate them. My error in understanding was to add the cpulimit at startup (of the user login). Here I cannot use sudo (well unless I visudo cpulimit, which I do not like doing). Maybe I should add the cpulimit to some boot script.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm not very familiar with boot scripts and so not sure if it could cause any different issues, if I were you I'd ask a question entitled something like: "How to set a boot-script on startup" and explain that you want to run CPU Limit on startup and link this post, I'd gladly set a [bounty](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/set-bounties) on your question as I'm quite interested to learn how to do this if possible.

Comment: There is a description on [http://askubuntu.com/questions/9382/how-can-i-configure-a-service-to-run-at-startup/9384#9384]. I have added `cpulimit -e whoopsie -l 3 &` to the file /etc/rc.local.

Comment: It should work, give it a try and once you've told me if it works I'll edit it into my answer so you can accept it :)

Comment: yes, adding `cpulimit -e whoopsie -l 3 &` to /etc/rc.local (before the exit statement) resolves my problem.