# I want to make Tomcat7 autostart at boot

Tags: automation, autostart

I installed tomcat servlet but I need to autostart it on boot. How to do that?

Comment: If you know the service name then autostart it using the method given in https://askubuntu.com/questions/9382/how-can-i-configure-a-service-to-run-at-startup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an `init` script for tomcat and add it to the correct `runlevel init` script.

Advice adapted from here http://www.raibledesigns.com/tomcat/boot-howto.html

Create an init script `/etc/init.d/tomcat/` for tomcat, changing the value for catalina home to the correct location:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# tomcat        
#
# chkconfig: 
# description:  Start up the Tomcat servlet engine.

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions


RETVAL=$?
CATALINA_HOME="/usr/apps/apache/tomcat/jakarta-tomcat-4.0.4"

case "$1" in
 start)
        if [ -f $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh ];
          then
        echo $"Starting Tomcat"
            /bin/su tomcat $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
        fi
    ;;
 stop)
        if [ -f $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh ];
          then
        echo $"Stopping Tomcat"
            /bin/su tomcat $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
        fi
    ;;
 *)
    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

Then add a link to the `rc5.d` folder - `/etc/rc5.d/`

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/tomcat /etc/rc5.d/S71tomcat
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to start the tomcat on the startup is to run it using cron using the @reboot attribute:

open up a terminal and type :

```
sudo crontab -e
```

at the end of the file enter the command:

```
@reboot /`PATH_TO_WHERE_TOMCAT_INSTALLED`/bin/startup.sh
```

save the file and exit.

The above command will run the command once everytime computer boots up.