# Does Ubuntu support "@reboot" in crontab?

Tags: cron

Does Ubuntu support `@reboot` in crontab?

I find documentation suggesting it is supported, but web chatter asserts it is not.

I cannot make the `@reboot` section work.
The "after midnight" section works fine.

Here is the test example from my `/etc/crontab`:

```bsh
$ cat /etc/crontab
# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
#
##

# in the beginning - 
@reboot /var/kiosk/btest.sh

# after midnight
30 0     * * *   root    /etc/cron.daily/kiosk/kioskReboot.sh

# end of crontab
```

#### shell script `btest.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
date > /var/kiosk/STARTFLAG.txt
echo we booted >> /var/kiosk/STARTFLAG.txt
date
echo we booted
```

#### permissions

```
$ ls -l btest.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 147 Aug 21 15:19 btest.sh
$ ls -ld
drwxrwxrwx 14 laptopsanytime root 4096 Aug 21 16:30 .
```

Comment: Have you thought about making the script btest.sh, autostart. http://askubuntu.com/a/9388/2973

Comment: There is a great answer on Unix & Linux' *[crontab's @reboot only works for root?][1]*

  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/109804/17362

Comment: I have in my personal crontab @reboot rule that works ok, looks like this:
`@reboot sh /home/me/run-stuff.sh`

Comment: In case nobody got it: he is mixing up crontabs: /etc/crontab is a user crontab and requires a user. crontab -e is the personal crontab and uses the user that is active at the moment of editing so does not require a username. Both accept @reboot.

Answer (score 27):

@reboot is supported in Ubuntu. The reason why your entry

```
@reboot /var/kiosk/btest.sh
```

doesn't work in /etc/crontab is because it's missing the user field. The correct syntax would be

```
@reboot root /var/kiosk/btest.sh
```

Comment: At least in 14.04 this is not the case, and wrong.  A "man 5 crontab" does not mention it either. Maybe it depends on the version, but I doubt it.

Comment: @vorburger if you mean `@reboot` is not supported, then here is a [link to wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto#line-1-10) that says it does. BTW, on my 14.04, `man 5 crontab` does tell about `@reboot`

Comment: On my Ubuntu 14.04, to have some user `someuser` automatically run a command on (re)boot, I had to add to **that user's** crontab an entry **without** specifying the username: `@reboot /var/kiosk/btest.sh`

Comment: Adding to the discussion, I am using ubuntu 16.4.05.  When using a users crontab,  @reboot command works without specifying the user to run as, and does not when the user is specified.

Comment: Works for me in Ubuntu 18.04.4 - `@reboot adb kill-server && sleep 1 && adb devices`

Comment: @KeithReynolds that is expected and exactly what the documentation says - in a user's crontab cron obviously already knows the user to run as

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS:
As root:

```
crontab -e
```

Add the following lines:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
@reboot /path_to_script.sh 2>&1 >> /path_to_log.log
```

2>&1 >> will output stdout to /path_to_log.log so you can troubleshoot this

Answer (score 0):

It works on 18.04 as job defined in `cron.d`.
I entered this in the job file:

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
@reboot root    /path/to/script.sh

Comment: adding root did not work for me. Did you use crontab -e as root?

Comment: I saved it to file start_at_reboot file in the /etc/cron.d directory,