# Run Android Studio on reboot using shell script

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts, cron, android-studio

I'd like to start Android Studio while my computer starting.
I used crontab and @reboot parameter:

```
crontab -e
```

and scheduled this task

```
@reboot /home/ziko/reboot_cron.sh # JOB_ID_1
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

then in my home dir added script - reboot_cron.sh

```
echo "It is now $(date +%T) on $(date +%A)" >> cron_reboot.log
/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

After restart my computer I  didn't see log in cron_reboot.log and Android Studio wasn't fired. What did I wrong?

UPD. I added second scheduled task and it works

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/bin/bash
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

@reboot root /home/ziko/reboot_cron.sh # don't work!
*/5 * * * * /home/ziko/mycrontest.sh   # it works!
```

And if I manully run reboot_cron.sh then it works but in crontab it don't!

Comment: In any case you probably need to chuck a shebang line into the first line script file - e.g. `#!/bin/sh`, `#!/bin/bash`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Did you try "@reboot root su -l ziko sh (script.sh)" from system crontab?

You may not get @reboot to work as non-root.

-

In system /etc/crontab:

```
@reboot root su -l (user_to_run_as) (your_sh_script)
```

or non-root 'crontab -e' user:

```
@reboot sh (your sh script)
```

( per : https://askubuntu.com/a/549646/169878 )

-

Note: I am not entirely sure if you need to be root to execute @reboot properly via crond under Ubuntu or Debian (or for that matter if it needs to be in the system wide crontab). Try the "@reboot sh " first and see if that works as non-root user.. Also consult https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/109804

EDIT:

Unless you really need this executed via crond, it might be a better idea to set this up as an *init* script (based on runlevel) or *rc.local* entry.. either one can be executed on a normal startup. Your script will execute after system is completely up. Since you do not need much more control over the script other than having it execute at startup (once), rc.local should be fine.

Example for "rc.local":

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

add this line *before* 'exit 0':

```
su -l ziko /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh
```

save.

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/rc.local
```

(Reboot.) 'studio.sh' should have executed/started as the ziko user on startup

Comment: Downvote with no comment. Uh ok.. My answer/@reboot works in etc system cron for me. If you cannot use root as user running script(s), su user you want script(s) run under (su -l ziko)

Comment: Hmmm, tried both variants(sh or root), it didn't work for me. Added one more schedule task (*/5 * * * * /home/ziko/mycrontest.sh), it worked as expected.

Comment: Glad it finally worked. Also - it may simply be a better idea to set this up as a init job or a simple rc.local entry.. either one would get executed on a normal startup.

Comment: And running "@reboot root" will not work out of a non-root crontab -e for obvious reasons.

Comment: Forgot to add: reason that works ^^^^ is you are simply re-executing it every 5mins. Please read what I wrote about possibly using rc.local (or init system) instead or running your script as given user from system crontab.

Comment: I found another good solution, maybe the best: I use native ubuntu tool as "Startup Application"

Comment: Good deal. ^ There are numerous ways to start something depending on what you have installed under Ubuntu and the needs of the application you are starting. Crond+@reboot is probably *the least ideal way* IMO.. to run a user application/script