# Run Python Script on OS boot

Tags: scripts, python, startup, init, init.d

This might be a question that has been repeated but i cannot find a correct way to do it .

What is my case ?
->I want to run a Python script.

What does the python script do in brief?
->The python script runs to setup a virtual private network.

How do I manually start it currently ?
->i use ./file.py start (this works)

what is not working ? 
->when i try to start in the beggining (boot ) it doesnot do anything. I am using cron job which is not working at all, and i dont want to use it , i want to use the /etc/init.d/ .

This is my file.conf in /etc/init/xxx.conf

```
description "file start script"
author "sijan <sijanshrestha2@gmail.com>"



exec python file.py start
exec sleep 10
exec ifconfig ip0 11.0.2.251

exec ip=`ifconfig ip0 | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'`

exec echo $ip >>/tmp/ip.log
```

I have added the python file in /etc/init.d/file.py

I am possibly not following the correct procedure to do this since i a very new to system level, however any idea on how to proceed is highly appreciated. I am very keen to get this fixed and learn

Comment: It looks to me you want to run it on log-in, a job for Startup Applications.

Comment: Depends on what python file does.  If it neess GUI,  run it via startup applications.  if it doesn't,  run via /etc/rc.local

Comment: Hi Serg, I am using A raspberry pi. The file is simple , it just setsup a virtual network . it does not need a GUI. I am having trouble figuring out the steps to correctly run in startup when system restarts if i put the file in /etc/init.d/file

Comment: ...Not only gui defines the time&place. Is it a *personal* virtual network?

Comment: Yes it is a personal virtual network.  If I run the script manually it works fine. But having trouble with automation.

Comment: Don't put scripts in `/etc/init.d`. Add a line in `/etc/rc.local`. Or, alternatively, configure the OpenVPN system service.

Comment: Hi sidzan, updated my answer. Do you manage?

Comment: I am still trying to get a hang of it .in visudo file i added `root ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /root/wtap.py`

and in rc.local i added `exec /root/wtap.py start` still having trouble. I am missing something that is causing this issue .

Comment: Could you @ ping me? else I miss the message :) You shouldn' t give * root* permission to run the script without password, but yourself.  *root* already has :).  Nothing to add to rc.local, since we don' t use that. simply store the script in `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Place the script into `/etc/rc.local` . Scripts there run as root when the system starts. It is also suitable for Raspberry Pi, as you specified in the comments.

In your case you want to run it as `python /path/to/script.py &`

Here's my sample `rc.local` file, I use the same approach to run battery and temperature monitoring scripts

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

/home/xieerqi/bin/batmon.sh &
/home/xieerqi/bin/preventShutdown.sh &
/home/xieerqi/bin/sh/temperature.sh  &
```

[Additional info on `/etc/rc.local`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/49635/85039)

Comment: Isn't he setting up the network as user? Not sure from the question, but it works when he runs once logged in *as user*.

Comment: for running manually the script  i do the following:
`sudo su` and 
`cd /root/` and 
`./file.py start`

So its just this command which works perfectly fine .

Comment: If he needs to provide username to setup VPN , that can be done inside the script.  From `rc.local` he doesn't need to provide his Raspberry user account

Comment: @sidzan ok so  add `python /root/file.py start  &` to `/etc/rc.local`

Answer (score 2):

You can also [do this with cron](https://superuser.com/questions/708149/how-to-use-reboot-in-etc-cron-d) by adding the following to your **crontab**:

```
@reboot username python /python/to/file.py
```

You may or [may not need the username](https://askubuntu.com/a/549646/89097) in there.

---

[EDIT]

There are two caveats to this approach:

1. the `cron` daemon must be running (which is the case under normal circumstances);
2. the script or the crontab file must include the environment variables (if any) that will be needed.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! nice one!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to end the string quotation after the email address, otherwise the other code will be considered part of the author string.