# cron tab not working in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, python, cron, django

I want to automate my application to run on server reboot,

following my code for adding shell script to crontab.

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
@reboot sh ~/start.sh
```

start.sh contains running the django application

logs are :

```
(CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
(CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
(root) CMD (/home/shiva/start.sh)
(shiva) CMD (sh ~/start.sh)
(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

Comment: Cron is clearly working,and trying to tell you about a problem with your script. Redirect the output to a file to read the error message.

Comment: help me on how to add output to a file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reasons why crontab does not work](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work)

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/23009 for output redirection examples.

Comment: hey unable to figure out solution.

Comment: Aha! There's the closer dupe:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/335615 . The same exact question, and the proper answer.

Comment: Post the contents of the script 'start.sh' if you need someone to help you out.

Comment: thanks for the help. am doing in another way like putting script in /etc/rc.0