# How to know if crontab implements @reboot?

Tags: cron

according to [crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/), many functions like @reboot, @daily, @annually ... are not standard. Is there any way to know the one implemented on my system (Kubuntu 21.04) ? I have tried the man-page, but have no result.

Thank you

Comment: way to know the one implemented on my system ? ... I guess we are supposed to know what your system is?

Comment: The best way to check is just to try it. Use with `@reboot` something that you can easily check for, for example create a particular file. If it works, then `@reboot` is supported. BTW. According to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/335615/does-ubuntu-support-reboot-in-crontab , `@reboot` is supported on Ubuntu at least since 16.04, so it should be supported on Kubuntu as well. Also try `man 5 crontab` and see if it mentions `@reboot`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The supported "special strings" for time specification are listed in `man 5 crontab`:

> ```
>    Instead  of the first five fields, one of eight special strings may ap‐
>    pear:
>
>           string         meaning
>           ------         -------
>           @reboot        Run once, at startup.
>           @yearly        Run once a year, "0 0 1 1 *".
>           @annually      (same as @yearly)
>           @monthly       Run once a month, "0 0 1 * *".
>           @weekly        Run once a week, "0 0 * * 0".
>           @daily         Run once a day, "0 0 * * *".
>           @midnight      (same as @daily)
>           @hourly        Run once an hour, "0 * * * *".
>
>    Please note that startup, as far as @reboot is concerned, is  the  time
>    when  the cron(8) daemon startup.  In particular, it may be before some
>    system daemons, or other facilities, were startup.  This is due to  the
>    boot order sequence of the machine.
> ```

If you don't believe the documentation for your system, then you may download the source (ex. `apt-get source cron`) and check the `entry.c` file:

```
cron-3.0pl1$ grep '!strcmp' entry.c
                if (!strcmp("reboot", cmd)) {
                } else if (!strcmp("yearly", cmd) || !strcmp("annually", cmd)){
                } else if (!strcmp("monthly", cmd)) {
                } else if (!strcmp("weekly", cmd)) {
                } else if (!strcmp("daily", cmd) || !strcmp("midnight", cmd)) {
                } else if (!strcmp("hourly", cmd)) {
```

Comment: You can do it even without the source by executing `strings $(which crontab) | grep "reboot"`