# What makes specific services (apache2, mysql) autostart?

Tags: apache2, services, autostart

Where can I set `services` `apache2` and `mysql` to do not start automatically? Or start when asked for it instead?

EDIT

BootUp-Manager worked for me very well disabling autostart of both services.

Comment: Have you looked at this question? I know it's the opposite, but it will give you a hint on where to look. Check the man page as they say in the answer, http://askubuntu.com/questions/9382/how-can-i-configure-a-service-to-run-at-startup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu uses both `sysvinit` as well as `upstart` for runlevel.

What you can do for `apache2` as I think apache2 doesnot have `upstart` configuration is:

`update-rc.d -f apache2 remove`

and for `mysql`. You need to edit `/etc/init/mysql.conf`

Search for line `start on` and comment it with `#`

`#start on runlevel [2345]`

Basically scripts and configuration which are started are located on

`/etc/init.d/`

`/etc/init/`

`/etc/init/` is for upstart configuration

Also you can use `BootUp-Manager` [Graphical Application] to disable services of `/etc/init.d/` but I donot think it works for `/etc/init/`

Just do:

`sudo apt-get install bum`