# Service isn't starting at startup

Tags: services

So I have a daemon in `/etc/init.d/` called TEST and it runs just fine if I run the command `service TEST start`. However I want it to start on startup so I looked into [How can I configure a service to run at startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9382/how-can-i-configure-a-service-to-run-at-startup) and when I run the command `sudo update-rc.d TEST defaults` it gives no output or errors so I assumed it worked correctly, however if I ever restart my pc it shows that the service TEST isn't running. I am running Ubuntu 17.04.

When I do the command `sudo update-rc.d TEST enable` I get the error:

```
update-rc.d: error: TEST Default-Start contains no runlevels, aborting.
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why are you using `update-rc.d` rather than `systemd`?

Comment: That was just from the tutorial that I found. How would I used systemd?

Comment: Your link is from 2010. Long before `systemd` came out. If you find systemd too complicated and prefer `cron` these decade old instructions still work for starting daemons: http://www.somacon.com/p38.php