# Asking for help to troubleshoot: Networking service not starting

Tags: networking

Since a while back my Ubuntu 23.10 (it was fresh installed) does not have a network connection on boot. After searching around for solutions I found that running `systemctl start systemd-resolved.service` restores the connection, but I have to run this every time I start the comupter, which is obviously annoying.

I realize it might be hard to spot the root issue from this description, but I know nothing about how the network works, or even what the `systemctl...` command does, hence I don't know where to start trouble shooting this so that I can ask for more specific help. Any suggestions on how to find the cause of this issue, or even better make it go away?

Comment: `systemctl enable systemd-resolved.service` ?

Comment: @DanielT Wow, that worked! Thanks! I guess some background service related to the network had for some reason been disabled?

Comment: This background service handles DNS. Perhaps it was buggy in previous releases so you tried to disable it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I configure a service to run at startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9382/how-can-i-configure-a-service-to-run-at-startup)

Comment: @DanielT Fresh install, and I didn't disable anything, but I did install a VPN, so maybe that software tampered with the settings somehow...

Comment: As for the other question, the network is something I kind of expect to work out of the box when I install an OS, so I wouldn't google for ”how to start a service” when it doesn't...